# Header of Navigation Drawer in android

Tags: android, header, navigation, drawer

I am wondering that how to implement the header on the navigation bar. Is it a kinda API or custom designed by Google?

Image Link: https://redpen.io/jecac9f1638a57e44f

Comment: you wan this header in one actiivty only?

Comment: how abt creating custom header with activity style as NOactionbar

Comment: no, I m wondering to implement login system, so curious about the top bar in navi. drawer.

Comment: as i could see from image the black box highlited is just a lienaer layout how difficuties u r facing ??

Comment: please provide the link if possible, how to implement this top bar (not only xml but with working java code).

Comment: i will not be able to find link matching extact to ur requirement but i could help u incase of difficulties..

Comment: thanks @diva, I want to implement the login functionality in navi drawer same as in google play store... i can't find the same thing... anyways thanks for help :)